# Fail to open merged pdf created with ITextSharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext, memorystream

I'm trying to merge some PDFs and save it to a blob storage in azure, the file is saving in azure I can see the Kbs there and download the file, but when I try to open it I get the "Failed to load PDF document"

```
public static bool MergePDFsAzure(IEnumerable<string> fileNames, string targetPdf, bool deleteInputFiles)
    {
        Stream finalStream = new MemoryStream();

        iTextSharp.text.Document document = new iTextSharp.text.Document();
        iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfCopy copy = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfCopy(document, finalStream);

        iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader.unethicalreading = true;
        try
        {
            copy.Open();
            document.Open();
            foreach (string file in fileNames)
            {
                var ms = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(file)) {
                    Position = 0 
                };

                copy.AddDocument(new PdfReader(ms));
                ms.Dispose();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ...

        }
        finally
        {
            if (document != null)
            {
                finalStream.Position = 0;
                StorageUtil.SaveFileAzure(...);
                document.Close();
                copy.Close();
            }
        }

    }
```

If I close the document before send to azure it crashes because the stream is disposed too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to close the `document` before sending the result to Azure. Otherwise the result simply is unfinished.

Unfortunately for your usage, though, the itext `PdfCopy` (and also the `PdfWriter` and the `PdfStamper`) closes its target stream when being closed itself implicitly during `document.Close()`.

To prevent that, you can ask itext not to do so by setting

```
copy.CloseStream = false;
```

before closing the document.

Alternatively you can retrieve the byte array represented by the memory stream with `finalStream.ToArray()` and use that byte array instead of a stream to store data elsewhere. Retrieving this byte array is also possible in case of closed memory streams.

Comment: Thanks it works! I tried your first solution to out the CloseStream before close the document.
About the byte[], do you think have a better performance?

Comment: *"About the byte[], do you think have a better performance?"* - I don't know but I don't assume so. A memory stream after all essentially already is a byte array with a stream API, so the export to Azure should take approximately similarly long, and calling `ToArray` adds the array copying to that. Depending on the exact use case, though, you may not be in a position to set the `CloseStream` property. In this case the `ToArray` approach is a viable alternative.